# Move conditional view logic to controller method

Tags: angularjs

We are currently looking at optimising our AngularJS views. At the moment, there is often quite a bit of conditional logic in the views to determine if something should show, e.g.:

```
ng-if="(vm.a && vm.b) || vm.c === 'something'"
```

It's not great to have this conditional logic in the views and are looking at moving this logic to the controller rather.

What is the best way to move this conditional logic out of the views and into the controller (where it belongs?

I've tried the following:

#### 1. Tried using variable

What I initially tried was creating a new variable in the controller:

```
this.showIt = (this.a && this.b) || this.c === 'something';
```

And then reference that variable in the view:

```
ng-if="vm.showIt"
```

But the issue is that the `this.showIt` doesn't update when the conditions change.

#### 2. Tried using method

Then I tried to move it to a method:

```
showIt(){ return (this.a && this.b) || this.c === 'something'; }
```

And then call that method in the view:

```
ng-if="vm.showIt()"
```

But this gets executed a lot of times.

#### 3. Considered calling method on change

```
this.showIt = false;
updateShowIt() { this.showIt = (vm.a && vm.b) || vm.c === 'something'; }
```

And then when one of the variables may have been changed, call `updateShowIt()`, but this will result in unmanageable code throughout the project, making the issue worse, rather than better.

Comment: There is no determinant answer for this - its all up to u. The only thing u didnt mention is writing component, but I wont advice doing it for one simple condition.

Comment: *But this gets executed a lot of times.*: it's execute as many times of the expression you had in the view. Do you want t make the view cleaner, or faster? If you don't have any performance problem, and just want to make the view cleaner, just use the method. If you want to make it faster, then measure first, because I doubt evaluating such a basic expression is the main probem.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, I agree. It will evaluate the expression just as much as the method, so that seems like the way to go. If you make it an answer, I can accept it.